# Ingress-Nginx-Controller failed to find the 2nd service deployed on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: service, google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

I deployed following 2 services (built in Java) on GCP:

- mply6 (service 1, listening on port 8080 external of GCP), corresponding to the URL: http://example.com/path1
- gami6 (service 2, listening on port 8081 external of GCP), corresponding to the URL: http://example.com/path2

The yaml to deploy and expose the service 1:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mply6
spec:
  selector: 
      app: mply6
  ports:
     - protocol: "TCP"
       port:  80
       targetPort:  8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "35.223.241.9"

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mply6
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: mply6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mply6
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mply6
        image: gcr.io/mply6-271000/mply6:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

The yaml to deploy and expose the service 2:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: gami6
spec:
  selector: 
      app: gmai6
  ports:
     - protocol: "TCP"
       port:  81
       targetPort:  8081
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "35.223.241.9"

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gami6
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: gami6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gami6
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gami6
        image: gcr.io/mply6-271000/gami6:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
```

And, the yaml to create the Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "35.223.241.9"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /path1
        backend:
          serviceName: mply6
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /path2
        backend:
          serviceName: gami6
          servicePort: 81
```

Furthermore, the result of 'kubectl describe ingress basic-ingress':

```
Name:             basic-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.244.199.199
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.60.1.4:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /multiplications/random   mply6:80 (10.60.0.32:8080)
        /results                  mply6:80 (10.60.0.32:8080)
        /leaders                  gami6:81 (10.60.0.32:8081)
        /stats                    gami6:81 (10.60.0.32:8081)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:  35.223.241.9
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From                      Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----                      -------
  Normal   CREATE     35m                   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/basic-ingress
  Warning  Translate  21m                   loadbalancer-controller   error while evaluating the ingress spec: could not find service "default/gami6"; could not find service"
default/gami6"
  Warning  Translate  6m17s (x34 over 77m)  loadbalancer-controller   error while evaluating the ingress spec: could not find port "8081" in service "default/gami6"; could no
t find port "8081" in service "default/gami6"
  Normal   CREATE     44s (x1153 over 22h)  loadbalancer-controller   ip: 35.244.199.199
  Normal   UPDATE     7s (x13 over 35m)     nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/basic-ingress
```

Basically I'm expecting that when I give the URL 'http://example.com/path2', the Ingress-Nginx-Controller would find the 2nd service 'gami6', but why is the above error message: could not find service "default/gami6"? (http://example.com/path1 can be found without a problem in the case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I’ve noticed a typo the second service yaml:

spec:
  selector: 
      app: gmai6 <-- should this be gami6?

To use Google’s Ingress with more than one backend you may need to use “NodePort” instead of “LoadBalancer” to expose the services. You can find about this on this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services

In case that you want to use nginx ingress controller you should follow this: guide: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

Comment: Thanks Lucas for spotting the typo(my silly mistake)!

It's the rootcause, which caused the service gami6 can't be connected to the pod on which  the image file is run.

It's also a good idea to use NodePort for exposing multiple backend services, will try it out!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add any remarks on the deployment you have above. However this deployment is very similar to the [http-balancer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer/web-service-v2.yaml)

I tried the deployment mentioned in the documentation and I was able to achieve what you are trying to do. Having a load-balancer routing requests based on the path.